# how update in sparql

Tags: sparql, rdf, n3

In my n3 data in rdf, i have the following data, and i want to change a little bit.
I have the value 'no' and i want to change that value to 'yes'

```
house:a1 a stand:Map;
    house:id "1"^^xsd:integer;
    house:sell "no";
```

I want to select that value 'sell? and change then, that is why i do the select

```
select ?sell where { 
   ?s stand:sell ?sell.
```

i want to delete tha value "no" and change to "yes" but i dont know how to do it, but i dont know how to do it.

Comment: SPARQL Update https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-update/ has a DELETE-INSERT-WHERE operation that can be used to make that change.